# force to close message when I make multiple clicks on button

Tags: android

my tab is the recent tab "Galaxy Tab 10.1"
this force close message appeared when I click multiple clicks in the application ( 4 to 5 clicks) repeatedly

what can i do to fix it?

this my code:

```
search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {  
        Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondScreenActivity.class);   
        nextScreen.putExtra("manufacturer",getm());  
        nextScreen.putExtra("model",getmo());  
        nextScreen.putExtra("year",gety());  
        startActivity(nextScreen);  
}
```

Comment: When you're throwing an `Exception`, add your log.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the button when it is clicked, so that there wont be multiple clicks.
    `button.setEnable(false);`

Then enable it in your nextScreen.